# How to split a string in to two and store 2 values in 2 variables in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, split

I want to split a phone number in to two,that is the country code and the number. A whitespace separates the two. I want to split the string and store it in an array such that I can get the country code using the `array[0]` variable and the rest of the number from `array[1]` variable. And I want to do this without using `explode()` function. Also, I cant use `str_split()` because the length of different country codes are different.

Example:

```
1) +91 8945696874
2) +1 78459654123
```

I want to get `+91` in one variable and `894569874` in another. Similarly `+1` in one variable and `78459654123` in another.
Any help are appreciated.

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/)**.

Comment: So whats the problem using `explode`? If it's a coding task from your teacher, what have you tried?

Comment: If I use explode the output can only be obtained by using print_r. and print_r will provide an Output like this "Array(    [0] => +919874784582)", which obviously, I cannot use in my input field

Comment: Is there always going to be a space there that separates the country digits from the rest?

Comment: @ShijithK what makes you think this? You can store the result of explode in a var without printing it somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$re = '/(\+[0-9]+)\s+([0-9]+)/'; // Pattern 
$str = '+91 8945696874 +1 78459654123'; // Phone numbers 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use **substr()** with **strrpos()**

**Note**: This is only works if your string contain only one country code and one mobile number, Otherwise go through @4EACH code.

```
$str = "+91 8945696874";

$cc = substr($str,0,strrpos($str," "));// Country code
$mn = substr($str,strrpos($str," ")+1);// Mobile number
```

Splitting string into two part by white space, 1st as country code 2nd as mobile number, So don't worry about length.

Comment: you should add +1, or $mn will include the space in front

Comment: Thanks! Added @Philipp

Answer (score -2):

Have you heard about the `expolde()` function?

```
$telNr= "+91 8945696874";

$your_array = explode(" ", $telNr);
echo $your_array[0]; // Output: +91
echo $your_array[1]; // Output: 8945696874
```

Edit: So I get downvoted due to OP don't want to use explode(). Have you seen his reason?

> If I use explode the output can only be obtained by using print_r. and
>   print_r will provide an Output like this "Array( [0] =>
>   +919874784582)", which obviously, I cannot use in my input field

Thats 100 % not true. If he would have tried my code he would see that the Output is exactly what he needs. But okay. Continue to downvote a good answer just cause OP don't know about how to output an array. lol

Comment: OP says: "And I want to do this without using explode function"

Comment: "And I want to do this without using explode() function"

Comment: @Pipe - Have you seen why poster doesn't want to use explode()

Comment: @MarkBaker no... and thats weird

Comment: @Pipe Look at my edit. For sure you can downvote me, but c'mon, is it really okay to downvote someone providing a good answer? OP doesn't want to use it because he has no idea how to output an array, not because it doesn't work. Just because an OP says he don't want to use X-function doesn't mean the solution shouldn't be with it. Sometimes its more important to look at the reasons about `WHY` he don't want to use such functions and may learn him something new. My answer would provide 100 % what he needs, he just doesn't know it.